# Creating const objects of user class from const pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Is it possible to force compiler propagate const-qualifier in my class, in order to supply const-pointers to the constructor? Consider the following code:

```
struct T
{
    T(int * a, int * b): 
        a(a), b(b) {}

    int * a;
    int * b;
};

int a = 1, b = 2;
const int * aRef = &a;
const int * bRef = &b;
const T obj(aRef, bRef); // error
```

This is clearly not allowed as constructor accepts `int *`, not `const int *`. Is there any way to achieve the same effect though, if there is no intention to modify the data at `a` and `b` in a `const` object of the class `T`?

**Edit** Here is a slightly more complicated example which is closer to actual problem. Imagine that I am passed sequentially a number of large arrays of `int[]` (say, 1000 integers in a row), and I want to evaluate running maximum of elements in `k`-th position (i.e. the running maximum is also 1000-int vector). As I am passed `const int *` to the start of the incoming array, I design a struct

```
struct ArrayWithMax
{
public:
    ArrayWithMax(int * array) : array(array) {}
    void Max(const ArrayWithMax& rhs);

private:
    int * array;
}
```

`ArrayWithMax::Max` will obviously cycle through both arrays, and assign the biggest value (`max(this->array[k], rhs.array[k]`) to the object's `array`. I'll skip the code for brevity.

Now, the variable I will store the result in has to be non-const (as the elements of the max-array will change). However the updates I receive are `const int *`. The easiest way for me would be to initialize `const ArrayWithMax` from `const int *`, which is exactly what the question tries to achieve.

Comment: In reality this is not int* but a pointer to a memory-heavy class I do not want to dereference and copy, hence the question.

Comment: And what should happen for non-const `T`?

Comment: I would argue that if the constructor requires non-const data, then either the constructor is under your control, and you can modify it to accept const data, or it is not, and then assuming that const data would suffice is wrong, even if that happens to be true today. You could obviously const_cast to eliminate the constness, but that smells of hack.

Comment: @LogicStuff I don't see any problem initializing non-const T object with non-const pointers; initializing non-const T object with const pointers is not required (and is indeed illogical).

Comment: @enrico-granata The constructor is indeed under my control. I cannot modify it to accept const data because I need non-const objects of type T to have non-const `a` and `b`. Const-cast is an option, but a rather ugly option given that I don't really want to break const rules.

Comment: Why not overload the constructor? Provide two versions, one with `const` and the other not

Comment: @Milo Lu I am not sure how that will help me: non-const T will not be able to initialize member pointers using const pointers.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want `obj.a[0] = 5;` to be allowed ?

Comment: @M.M Only for non-const objects of type T.

Comment: This sounds like you either need two classes entirely - ConstT and NotConstT - or you need a TFactory that can construct either a const T with const data or a non-const T with non-const data. I would go for the former approach: have a ConstT, a NonConstT class, each with appropriate constructors, and whatever interop among the two you need, just becomes method overloads in either class. You can probably generate most of the boilerplate with preprocessor magic.

Comment: I can't help but agree with @vlad_tepesch that this entire design problem smells of fishy and hacky. XY problem maybe?

Comment: @EnricoGranata Yes, having two classes is possible. I do wonder however whether the language has a facility for making a relatively straightforward disclosure to the compiler that "for the const objects of type T the pointers will be const, and can be initialized accordingly from other const pointers".

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you want is for:

```
const T obj(aRef, bRef);
```

to result in an object where you can't modify the integer the pointers point to. Which means having the member pointers being either `int const* const` or `int const*`.

The reality is that the `const` there is simply propagating to the member making them both `int* const`, which simply means that once the pointers are set they cannot changed.

You can achieve what you want via something like:

```
template<typename Type>
struct T {
    T(Type* a, Type* b): 
        a(a), b(b) {}

    Type* a;
    Type* b;
};
```

and then:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int const* aRef = &a;
int const* bRef = &b;
T<int const> obj(aRef, bRef);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b48a9090e06db862)

If you also want the pointers themselves to be `const`, then you can use:

```
T<int const> const obj(aRef, bRef);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a hack --- I need objects of type T interacting with each other in a non-trivial fashion (for instance, I need things like T::Op(const& T rhs) for further use in templates), so this workaround will unravel pretty quickly. It would seem to me that const-cast is more elegant solution by comparison.

Comment: @random Wait, this solution is a "hack" but `const_cast` is elegant? Also why will it unravel? You can make the `rhs` take a template argument itself. For example `template<typename Type> T::Op(T<Type> const& rhs)`.

Comment: Yes, `const_cast` is a hack as well, but it's a simple straightforward hack, if I may put it so. Yes, I can template this to oblivion, and maybe even should, but when I say "unravel" I mean precisely that I will have to account for this templated alternatives at every turn, when I really just want a `strongly const T` object, with propagated const-qualifier. Don't get me wrong, I agree you can achieve technically working code using the code you suggest (as with `const_cast`).

Comment: @random If I'd use _a hack_ at all, I'd prefer the shorter one. It's beyond matters then already.

Comment: @random The `const_cast` alternative would remove constness not add it. It would not result in a "strongly constant `T`" at all. While this alternative actually does. The resulting object from `const_cast`ing away the `const`-ness of the pointers passed would only result in an object where the pointers can't be modified but what the pointers point to can be modified.

Comment: @Shoe We are talking past each other. Yes, const_cast will break the constness, not propagate it (which is why it's a hack). You might disagree, but the way I view it from "language user" perspective, if I cannot achieve the desired effect ("strong const") I will just live without const, rather than use workarounds which will (among other consequences) force me to keep my class in header files.

Comment: @random please add an example of your interaction to your question. May be we can aid in working out a good solution. I can't help but something on this design smells fishy to me. Casting const away may lead to hidden bugs because the compiler may rely on the constness and adding that the object is not changed in deeper levels

Answer (score 1):

You could use inheritance, like so:

```
struct CT
{
    CT(int const * a, int const * b) :
        a(a), b(b) {}

    int const * ca;
    int const * cb;
};

struct T : CT
{
    T(int * a, int * b) :
        CT(a, b) {}

    int * a() const { return const_cast<int *>(ca); }
    int * b() const { return const_cast<int *>(cb); }    
};
```

Or you could make `CT` and `T` unrelated types and provide implicit conversion from `T` to `CT`.

I really wouldn't want to do this via `const T` vs. `T`. It's non-intuitive. Also you would have to disable the default copy-ctor. Otherwise one could always create a non-const copy from a const-ref, and then use that non-const copy to modify `*a` or `*b`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand. You want to first call `ArrayWithMax`with your own writable storage, `int*`, and from then on, you will call it with your received non-mutable storage, `int const *`. You will then pass these non-mutable `ArrayWithMax` to your mutable's `ArrayWithMax::Max()` to evaluate your running maximum. Assuming this is want you want, I kind of agree with vlad_tepesch in that the design may need some work. That said, I would do it with templates like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 2;   // hardcoded for now; it could be 1000

template <typename T>
class ArrayWithMax
{
public:
    ArrayWithMax(T array) : array_(array){}

    // Max will accept any class, as long as it provides U::begin() const
    // Max will not be generated when type T is const.
    template <typename U>
    void Max(const U& rhs)
    {
        transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(),
            [] (auto a, auto b) { return max(a, b); } );
    }

    T begin() { return array_; }
    T end() { return array_+size(); }

    T begin() const { return array_; }
    T end() const { return array_+size(); }
    size_t size() const { return ARRAY_SIZE; }

private:
    T array_;
};

int main()
{
    // some data to test with
    int someArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    someArray[0] = 1;
    someArray[1] = 2;
    int const * received = someArray;

    int someArray2[ARRAY_SIZE];
    someArray2[0] = 0;
    someArray2[1] = 8;
    int const * received2 = someArray2;

    // to store max
    int myStorage[ARRAY_SIZE];
    memset(myStorage, 0, sizeof(myStorage));

    int* aWithMax = myStorage;

    // first mutable ArrayWithMax with myStorage
    ArrayWithMax<int*> a(aWithMax);

    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    // other ArrayWithMax with const int*
    ArrayWithMax<const int*> receivedArray(received);
    a.Max(receivedArray);

    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    // and another
    ArrayWithMax<const int*> receivedArray2(received2);
    a.Max(receivedArray2);

    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

This program was compiled as shown below, and it produces the following output:

```
Luiss-Air:const luis$ g++-5.3.0 -std=c++14 ArrayWithMax.C 
Luiss-Air:const luis$ a.out
0 0 
1 2 
1 8 
Luiss-Air:const luis$
```

If `ArrayWithMax` only calculates the running max, consider just using std::transform:

```
    // this does what you want to do with your class
    transform(aWithMax, aWithMax+ARRAY_SIZE, received, aWithMax,
        [] (auto a, auto b) { return max(a, b); });
```

Comment: Luis, please see the example I've just added. I am not sure I see how to modify your code to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @random, see the edit to my answer. I am assuming that you are supposed to modify the array they are passing you. If that is the case, why are they passing you `const int*`?

Comment: Also, how do you know how big the array is?

Comment: No, I am not modifying the arrays I receive (I receive several sequentially). I do want to create my own array, and "apply" (via ::Max) the arrays I am passed to this array.

Comment: @random, I edited my response again. Hopefully, this time I understood what you want.

Comment: Luis, you are correct in describing my problem. I have upvoted your solution, but I can't officially "accept" it because my initial question was not about just coding the ArrayMax class (there are several ways to do that and I personally prefer the const_cast approach as I dislike templates). Rather, I wanted to know if there are any facilities in the language, like special keywords or notations, that would achieve propagating const-ness to pointer members of the class. It seems the correct answer is "none", which to me looks like a strange omission in the language.

Comment: random, "const-ness" does "propagate" to pointer members of the class/struct. Take your initial `struct T` and create a const T: `const T obj(&a, &b);` You won't be able to modify obj.a or obj.b. `obj.a = &b` will generate a compiler error, which would not be generated if you had instantiated it as mutable: `T obj(&a, &b);` T::a and T::b are "pointers to int" and in a `const T`, they are "const pointers to int". I know that you would like them to be "converted" to "pointers to const int" but that is a different type, and it is not how it works.

Comment: Your option is to create a class that behaves as you desire, with templates or const_cast<>. I know that you don't like templates, but I consider them a better option because you don't risk accidentally modifying the arrays that you receive. Templates keep the type of those pointers as `int const *` (i.e pointers to const int) while const_cast<> removes the "const-ness" from the pointers. Templates take a bit of getting used to, but once you do, they are not so bad. And they are very powerful.